# Dynamic Drop down not working in IE11?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, internet-explorer

```
var vehicleLineDD = document.getElementById("vehicleLineDD");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    vehicleLineOp.text = arr[i].code + ': ' + arr[i].desc;
    vehicleLineOp.value = arr[i].code;
    vehicleLineDD.add(vehicleLineOp, null);
}
```

Hi Friends, here I am attach my code where I have struck now.
Problem is vehicleLineDD is the dynamic drop down. Depends on another drop down I should load the values here.
It is working fine in IE8, but in IE11 all the values are coming properly except **vehicleLineDD.add(vehicleLineOp, null);**
is not adding the values, only last value alone added. Every time when change the first drop down here I can see only one option.
Could anyone help me to come out from the the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you defining `vehicleLineOp`?

Comment: Before these codes I defined vehicleLineOp
Actual problem is in the .add method alone
since I put alert before add method it gives proper result, but it doesn't comes to drop down because of not added in the vehicleLineDD (IE11)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a new option element for the vehicleLineOp variable(using code similar to `vehicleLineOp = document.createElement("option");`), otherwise you're just constantly updating the same option element with different text and value attributes (which is why only the last applied text and value are showing up).

```
var vehicleLineOp;
var vehicleLineDD = document.getElementById("vehicleLineDD");
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    vehicleLineOp = document.createElement("option");
    vehicleLineOp.text = arr[i].code + ': ' + arr[i].desc;
    vehicleLineOp.value = arr[i].code;
    vehicleLineDD.add(vehicleLineOp);
}
```

Edit: Here's a working example that should work in both IE11 and IE8:

```js
function populate() {
  var arr = document.getElementById("input").value.split("\n");
  var vehicleLineOp;
  var vehicleLineDD = document.getElementById("vehicleLineDD");
  vehicleLineDD.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    vehicleLineOp = document.createElement("option");
    vehicleLineOp.text = arr[i];
    vehicleLineOp.value = arr[i];
    vehicleLineDD.add(vehicleLineOp);
  }
}
var btn = document.getElementById("btnPopulate");
if (btn.addEventListener) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", populate);
} else {
  btn.attachEvent("onclick", populate);
}
```

```html
Add each choice as a new line in the text area below, thn click "Populate Dropdown":<br/>
<textarea id="input" style="vertical-align:top;height:4em;">Example 1
Example 2
Example 3</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Populate Dropdown" id="btnPopulate" />
<br/>
<select id="vehicleLineDD"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Thriggle.
I already have the vehicleLineOp = document.createElement("option");
So may be I updated the same location with different value as you said. But it is working fine in IE8. Is there any code change here for IE11??

Comment: There've been a lot of changes between IE8 and IE11, especially with how IE11 interprets HTML and JavaScript. IE11 is significantly closer to the HTML and Ecmascript standards; if it behaves differently, the odds are that it is behaving the way it *should* be, and that IE8 was interpreting your code in a non-standard way.

Comment: Ok, Noted.
Do we have any alternative code for my above codes, which can work on IE11..

Comment: @Maharajan I updated my answer with a code example that should work in both IE8 and IE11

Comment: Thank you very much for you timely help @Thriggle
Let me check with this, it is useful for me.